# Select tag is breaking up a word

Tags: html, css

I have a form in a web page and a select tag is breaking up the text inside it inappropriately like this:

[image: Select tag]

It is breaking up the work "Banking" for some reason. I have tried to prevent this with de CSS attribute `word-break: keep-all` but it does nothing.

The HTML and CSS are like this:

```
<select name="your-Detalle" 
        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" 
        aria-required="true" 
        aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="Operaciones con Tarjeta de Débito">
    Operaciones con Tarjeta de Débito
  </option>
  <option value="Operaciones con Tarjeta de Crédito">
    Operaciones con Tarjeta de Crédito
  </option>
  <option value="Operaciones de Internet Banking">
    Operaciones de Internet Banking
  </option>
</select>
```

---

```
select {
    font-family: Futura-medium;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    height: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #666666;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

I'm not sure if is relevant but the entire form is done in WordPress with Contact Form 7.

**EDIT**

If you add the attribute `white-space: nowrap;` it swallows the overflow:
[image]

Comment: Is the `200px` width changeable?  You need to use `white-space:nowrap` if you don't want it to break.  But this will hide long text.   There's no other way to show all of the text in a select box without making the select box wider.

Comment: Yeah, this is happening because you have a fixed width for your input field

Comment: If you tried word break then you should understand that the word Banking is not fitting into its parent container, due to the width of the element. It may also be a good idea to use hyphens with your word break property like so: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how important it is for your container `select` to have a fixed width of 200px, but this is causing the line of text to break. Two solutions are available to you:

1. Change the `width: 200px` to `min-width: 200px` which will expand to the width of the text in the options of your select box.
2. Add the `word-break: break-word` and `hyphens: auto` properties to your CSS... which may help but will certainly not look as good as what I wrote on option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the white-space property to your `select` CSS class:

```
select {
    /*... other properties ...*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: It swallows the overflow. I'll edit a post an image.

Comment: Please share the URL if you can @DavidPrieto

Comment: Sorry, I can't @CreativePs